# ¿Cómo soluciono este error PHP: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Actualmente tengo un problema al querer mostrar los usuarios registrados en mi web

El código es el siguiente:

```
function conseguirDatosRegistrados($conexion){
$consulta = "SELECT id FROM usuarios";
$ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$resultado = [];

if ($ejecucion && mysqli_num_rows($ejecucion)>=1 ) {
    $resultado = $ejecucion;
}

return $resultado;
}
```

y aquí el front

```
<div class="bloque">
    <h4>DATOS</h4>
    <hr>
    <?php

        $consulta = conseguirDatosRegistrados($db);
        if ($consulta == true):
    ?>
    <p>Usuarios registrados: <?=$consulta?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

No puedo solucionar el error

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: Hola Cristian. Hemos observado que tienes numerosas preguntas con buenas respuestas y sin embargo no has aceptado respuesta. Considera por favor marcar las respuestas útiles como aceptadas para que los futuros usuarios puedan identificar rápidamente la respuesta que te funcionó, y para agradecer tambien a los que te han ayudado.Como te comenta @Marcos, si tienes alguna duda lee por favor los enlaces que te ha proporcionado en su comentario.

Answer (score 3):

¿Por qué cuentas los registros con el PHP? Mejor que te lo diga la base de datos.
Te dejo un ejemplo documentado

```
function conseguirDatosRegistrados($conexion) {
 // Contamos los registros en lugar de traerlos todos
 $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'COUNT' FROM usuarios";

 // Revisamos si la consulta tiene algun error
 if ( !$ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) ) {
   return 'Error en la consulta';

 } else {
   // Sacamos el número de registros de la consulta
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $ejecucion );

   //Acostumbrate a liberar memoria cada que hagas un SELECT
   mysqli_free_result( $ejecucion );
   return $row['COUNT'];
 }
}
```

Así ya debería funcionar, más limpio y sencillo

```
<div class="bloque">
    <h4>DATOS</h4>
    <hr>
    <?php      
       echo "<p>Usuarios registrados: { conseguirDatosRegistrados( $db ) }</p>";
     ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos errores que hay visiblemente, en ambos archivos, en primer lugar como guardas los resultados en el arreglo y segundo, como lo imprimes

`PHP`

```
function conseguirDatosRegistrados($conexion){
$consulta = "SELECT id FROM usuarios";
$ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$resultado = [];

if ($ejecucion && mysqli_num_rows($ejecucion)>=1 ) {
    $resultado[] = $ejecucion; //Especifica que es un arreglo con los corchetes y guarde bien los datos que llegan
}

return $resultado;
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="bloque">
    <h4>DATOS</h4>
    <hr>
    <?php

        $consulta = conseguirDatosRegistrados($db);
        if ($consulta == true):
           for($i=0; $i < count($consulta); $i++){          
              echo "<p>Usuarios registrados: {$consulta[$i]["user"]}</p>"
           }
        endif;
?>
</div>
```

Algo así solucionaría tu problema, recuerda que estás guardando los resultados en un arreglo, por lo tanto el arreglo para imprimirlo debes decirle la posición a la cual quieres imprimir, y ya que estamos hablando de una consulta, entonces, pide tanto la posición, como el campo que quieres imprimir, entonces lo que haces es recorrer un ciclo con la cantidad de posiciones que tiene el arreglo, que es igual a la cantidad de registros que tienen en la tabla de la cual haces la consulta, y con la variable `$i` le dices la posición, ya que la variable va sumando 1 cada que termina el ciclo, de ahí le señalas la columna a mostrar y listo. Espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que `mysqli_query()` devuelve un `objeto` a tu variable `$ejecucion`, no un `string`.

```
if ($ejecucion && mysqli_num_rows($ejecucion)>=1 ) {
    $resultado[] = $ejecucion["id"]; // Tienes que especificar la columna
}
```